# filtering d3 mercator map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, geojson

I am using [Alan McConchie's](http://bl.ocks.org/almccon/6ab03506d2e3ff9d843f69fa2d5c29cf) block for a basic mercator map in d3. I've gotten it to work locally but am trying to filter the map to exclude certain countries (Antarctica for example).

I don't want to simply remove it from the json file in case I ever need to bring it back and would rather find a non-destructive solution. From my digging, I think there is a way to filter using the code below in d3 based on country code but can't get it to work based on the example I'm using. Where do I include the filter? Before the map has been drawn? After the data has loaded?

Any better solutions for removing countries?

`.data(geo_data.features.filter(d => d.id !== "ATA))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does not filter in-place:

> filter() does not mutate the array on which it is called.

You'll have to reassign the value. For instance:

```
geojson.features = geojson.features.filter(d => d.id !== "ATA");
```

Here is the bl.ocks with that change (no Antarctica anymore): http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/8ef6910d243e4f7a200cd6c231eb44f1/e63d0a10b4629cdee795660c9fc542207d7dc82f

However, this will remove Antarctica from the loaded data. As you want a non-destructive solution, do a deep clone first and then use the filter:

```
var filteredGeojson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(geojson));
filteredGeojson.features = filteredGeojson.features.filter(d => d.id !== "ATA");
```

Finally, for using your snippet...

```
.data(geojson.features.filter(d => d.id !== "ATA"))
```

... which, by the way, works just fine, you'll have to create an "enter" selection:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(geojson.features.filter(d => d.id !== "ATA"))
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d){
        return path(d)})
    });
```

The problem, as you can see, is that each country will be a separate path, and I'm not sure if that's what you want: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/ae26c13f2ed863afbb905f598a48a0e3/3d7323cf9f016c0e19aa1c1d876e492715105819

Comment: @LexiN the snippet in your question works just fine, **if** you create an enter selection, which doesn't exist in that original bl.ocks. Have a look at my answer again.

Comment: @GerardoFurtadoThanks for going back and amending! I actually will need separate paths so this saves me a headache down the line.